# Flask / Python context debugging

Tags: python, flask

I'm used to using ipdb with django. Is there a way to use it or some other context debugger in flask?

If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Flask (Werkzeug actually) comes with a built-in interactive debugger. To use it, just basically call `Raise` anywhere in your view function and load a url pointing to this view in your browser. You will have access to a nice and powerful tool.

[Link to Werkzeug's debugger documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/debug/).